# Draw a Jpanel's border without resizing content (Java)

Tags: java, swing, jpanel, border

I have a column of `JPanel` instances that has content in it, that when it is clicked, the selected Panel is set to have a border (in order to distinguish it), and only 1 at a time has the border.

The problem is that when it sets the border, it sets the outer section of the panel to the border, and shrinks the content inside. Although it seems minor it is not very professional, and I would much rather have it add more like an overlay, where the content will not shrink.

I am thinking maybe there is some method of graphics that will let me do this? I haven't been able to find any way of doing this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Start by setting all the components to have a `EmptyBorder` set to a single pixel inset.

When you select a panel, simply set the newly selected panel's border as you are (presumably using a `LineBorder`) and the set the previously selected panel's border to the single pixel `EmptyBorder`.

If you're clever, you could get away with a single instance of `EmptyBorder` ;)